# How to output 5.1 surround on OS X with libvlc?

Tags: macos, core-audio, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to get my app written to use libvlc to output surround (AC3 5.1) over an HDMI sound device.

The HDMI device is called "HDMI" in the Audio Devices in OSX.

I have tried using `libvlc_audio_output_device_set`, where I have tried "coreaudio", "auhal" and "HDMI" as the name, and the ID number as the id. I am not sure if this is right, the documents talk of non-portability and specificness to this call.

I have also tried passing arguments when initialising libvlc:

- "--aout=auhal"
- "core-audio-dev 40"

40 is the ID fro the HDMI device (determined with a dynamic library I have which obtains the device ID number for a specific Audio Device), but in this case I get the error:

```
vlc: unknown option or missing mandatory argument `--coreaudio-dev 40'
```

The VLC documentation says this is an option on OSX but it seems not to work.

Selecting audio device in the standalone VLC app works fine (select HDMI).

I am using nightly VLC on OS X 10.8.3.

Can anyone help?